# what is the best way to implement a mapper in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have three request objects called Request1To,Request2To,Request3To.
I want to have a method that takes in any of these TO's and return a response object.
I have currently implemented like this

```
class Mapper{
     public ResponseTo mapRequest1(Request1To){

      }

     public ResponseTo mapRequest2(Request2To){

      }

    public ResponseTo mapRequest3(Request3To){

      }

}
```

Is there a better way to do this instead of creating a seperate method for each request object?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) and [modelmapper](http://modelmapper.org/).  They are both excellent tools for mapping one object to another.  I know that Dozer integrates with Spring.  In Dozer your code will look something like this:

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
ResponseTo response = mapper.map(request, ResponseTo.class);
```

It's very powerful and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing more of what those objects are like... just make a Request interface they all implement. Then the mapRequest method will take in the interface instead of the concrete class.

Comment: mapping for each request object is different.I need to have an if condition inside the mapRequest method to find what the instance type is and then do mapping which i dont like.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface CustomRequest {


 public ResponseTo convertResponseTo();


}


public class Request1To implements CustomRequest{

    public ResponseTo convertResponseTo(){

     // do the logic and return response

    }

 }


  public class Mapper {


   public ResponseTo mapRequest(CustomRequest request){

      return request.convertResponseTo();

  }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to have chained if conditions.

Comment: I changed my Answer check it

Comment: I need to have the mapping logic in transferobject which i don't want to do.As having mapping logic in transfer object ties it to a particular response type.